# Make light pass throught Smooth Portals in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, graphical-programming

I am using Sebastian Lague portals in my game ([text](https://github.com/SebLague/Portals)), everything works perfectly but there is an catch, I have a flashlight machanic in my project and when I get close to the portal with it it looks really messy and completelly destroys the illusion.

I was thinking about ways to fix it and I mainly got two ideas:

- The cameras in the other side of the portal could also have their own flashlight, which would create a illusion that the light passed throught the portal.
- Really make the light render throught the portal (I have actually no idea about how to do it)

I tried to implement the first solution and got some good results in general, it looks really smooth if you are facing the portal directly in front of it and don't go the borders, however, once you face it sideways or start looking to one of its corners the camera in the other side of the portal stops moving and the flashlight stops too, which completelly destroyed my illusion. (I recorder what was happening to be more precise: [text](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2BetUfRSlE))

Ideally, I think that making the light render throught the portal and act like a continuation of it's path after colliding with it would be perfect, even thought I no clue about how to do it.

Here are the codes:

portal.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Portal : MonoBehaviour {
    [Header ("Main Settings")]
    public Portal linkedPortal;
    public MeshRenderer screen;
    public int recursionLimit = 5;

    [Header ("Advanced Settings")]
    public float nearClipOffset = 0.05f;
    public float nearClipLimit = 0.2f;

    // Private variables
    RenderTexture viewTexture;
    Camera portalCam;
    Camera playerCam;
    Material firstRecursionMat;
    List<PortalTraveller> trackedTravellers;
    MeshFilter screenMeshFilter;

    void Awake () {
        playerCam = Camera.main;
        portalCam = GetComponentInChildren<Camera> ();
        portalCam.enabled = false;
        trackedTravellers = new List<PortalTraveller> ();
        screenMeshFilter = screen.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ();
        screen.material.SetInt ("displayMask", 1);
    }

    void LateUpdate () {
        HandleTravellers ();
    }

    void HandleTravellers () {

        for (int i = 0; i < trackedTravellers.Count; i++) {
            PortalTraveller traveller = trackedTravellers[i];
            Transform travellerT = traveller.transform;
            var m = linkedPortal.transform.localToWorldMatrix * transform.worldToLocalMatrix * travellerT.localToWorldMatrix;

            Vector3 offsetFromPortal = travellerT.position - transform.position;
            int portalSide = System.Math.Sign (Vector3.Dot (offsetFromPortal, transform.forward));
            int portalSideOld = System.Math.Sign (Vector3.Dot (traveller.previousOffsetFromPortal, transform.forward));
            // Teleport the traveller if it has crossed from one side of the portal to the other
            if (portalSide != portalSideOld) {
                var positionOld = travellerT.position;
                var rotOld = travellerT.rotation;
                traveller.Teleport (transform, linkedPortal.transform, m.GetColumn (3), m.rotation);
                traveller.graphicsClone.transform.SetPositionAndRotation (positionOld, rotOld);
                // Can't rely on OnTriggerEnter/Exit to be called next frame since it depends on when FixedUpdate runs
                linkedPortal.OnTravellerEnterPortal (traveller);
                trackedTravellers.RemoveAt (i);
                i--;

            } else {
                traveller.graphicsClone.transform.SetPositionAndRotation (m.GetColumn (3), m.rotation);
                //UpdateSliceParams (traveller);
                traveller.previousOffsetFromPortal = offsetFromPortal;
            }
        }
    }

    // Called before any portal cameras are rendered for the current frame
    public void PrePortalRender () {
        foreach (var traveller in trackedTravellers) {
            UpdateSliceParams (traveller);
        }
    }

    // Manually render the camera attached to this portal
    // Called after PrePortalRender, and before PostPortalRender
    public void Render () {

        // Skip rendering the view from this portal if player is not looking at the linked portal
        if (!CameraUtility.VisibleFromCamera (linkedPortal.screen, playerCam)) {
            return;
        }

        CreateViewTexture ();

        var localToWorldMatrix = playerCam.transform.localToWorldMatrix;
        var renderPositions = new Vector3[recursionLimit];
        var renderRotations = new Quaternion[recursionLimit];

        int startIndex = 0;
        portalCam.projectionMatrix = playerCam.projectionMatrix;
        for (int i = 0; i < recursionLimit; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                // No need for recursive rendering if linked portal is not visible through this portal
                if (!CameraUtility.BoundsOverlap (screenMeshFilter, linkedPortal.screenMeshFilter, portalCam)) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            localToWorldMatrix = transform.localToWorldMatrix * linkedPortal.transform.worldToLocalMatrix * localToWorldMatrix;
            int renderOrderIndex = recursionLimit - i - 1;
            renderPositions[renderOrderIndex] = localToWorldMatrix.GetColumn (3);
            renderRotations[renderOrderIndex] = localToWorldMatrix.rotation;

            portalCam.transform.SetPositionAndRotation (renderPositions[renderOrderIndex], renderRotations[renderOrderIndex]);
            startIndex = renderOrderIndex;
        }

        // Hide screen so that camera can see through portal
        screen.shadowCastingMode = UnityEngine.Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.ShadowsOnly;
        linkedPortal.screen.material.SetInt ("displayMask", 0);

        for (int i = startIndex; i < recursionLimit; i++) {
            portalCam.transform.SetPositionAndRotation (renderPositions[i], renderRotations[i]);
            SetNearClipPlane ();
            HandleClipping ();
            portalCam.Render ();

            if (i == startIndex) {
                linkedPortal.screen.material.SetInt ("displayMask", 1);
            }
        }

        // Unhide objects hidden at start of render
        screen.shadowCastingMode = UnityEngine.Rendering.ShadowCastingMode.On;
    }

    void HandleClipping () {
        // There are two main graphical issues when slicing travellers
        // 1. Tiny sliver of mesh drawn on backside of portal
        //    Ideally the oblique clip plane would sort this out, but even with 0 offset, tiny sliver still visible
        // 2. Tiny seam between the sliced mesh, and the rest of the model drawn onto the portal screen
        // This function tries to address these issues by modifying the slice parameters when rendering the view from the portal
        // Would be great if this could be fixed more elegantly, but this is the best I can figure out for now
        const float hideDst = -1000;
        const float showDst = 1000;
        float screenThickness = linkedPortal.ProtectScreenFromClipping (portalCam.transform.position);

        foreach (var traveller in trackedTravellers) {
            if (SameSideOfPortal (traveller.transform.position, portalCamPos)) {
                // Addresses issue 1
                traveller.SetSliceOffsetDst (hideDst, false);
            } else {
                // Addresses issue 2
                traveller.SetSliceOffsetDst (showDst, false);
            }

            // Ensure clone is properly sliced, in case it's visible through this portal:
            int cloneSideOfLinkedPortal = -SideOfPortal (traveller.transform.position);
            bool camSameSideAsClone = linkedPortal.SideOfPortal (portalCamPos) == cloneSideOfLinkedPortal;
            if (camSameSideAsClone) {
                traveller.SetSliceOffsetDst (screenThickness, true);
            } else {
                traveller.SetSliceOffsetDst (-screenThickness, true);
            }
        }

        var offsetFromPortalToCam = portalCamPos - transform.position;
        foreach (var linkedTraveller in linkedPortal.trackedTravellers) {
            var travellerPos = linkedTraveller.graphicsObject.transform.position;
            var clonePos = linkedTraveller.graphicsClone.transform.position;
            // Handle clone of linked portal coming through this portal:
            bool cloneOnSameSideAsCam = linkedPortal.SideOfPortal (travellerPos) != SideOfPortal (portalCamPos);
            if (cloneOnSameSideAsCam) {
                // Addresses issue 1
                linkedTraveller.SetSliceOffsetDst (hideDst, true);
            } else {
                // Addresses issue 2
                linkedTraveller.SetSliceOffsetDst (showDst, true);
            }

            // Ensure traveller of linked portal is properly sliced, in case it's visible through this portal:
            bool camSameSideAsTraveller = linkedPortal.SameSideOfPortal (linkedTraveller.transform.position, portalCamPos);
            if (camSameSideAsTraveller) {
                linkedTraveller.SetSliceOffsetDst (screenThickness, false);
            } else {
                linkedTraveller.SetSliceOffsetDst (-screenThickness, false);
            }
        }
    }

    // Called once all portals have been rendered, but before the player camera renders
    public void PostPortalRender () {
        foreach (var traveller in trackedTravellers) {
            UpdateSliceParams (traveller);
        }
        ProtectScreenFromClipping (playerCam.transform.position);
    }
    void CreateViewTexture () {
        if (viewTexture == null || viewTexture.width != Screen.width || viewTexture.height != Screen.height) {
            if (viewTexture != null) {
                viewTexture.Release ();
            }
            viewTexture = new RenderTexture (Screen.width, Screen.height, 0);
            // Render the view from the portal camera to the view texture
            portalCam.targetTexture = viewTexture;
            // Display the view texture on the screen of the linked portal
            linkedPortal.screen.material.SetTexture ("_MainTex", viewTexture);
        }
    }

    // Sets the thickness of the portal screen so as not to clip with camera near plane when player goes through
    float ProtectScreenFromClipping (Vector3 viewPoint) {
        float halfHeight = playerCam.nearClipPlane * Mathf.Tan (playerCam.fieldOfView * 0.5f * Mathf.Deg2Rad);
        float halfWidth = halfHeight * playerCam.aspect;
        float dstToNearClipPlaneCorner = new Vector3 (halfWidth, halfHeight, playerCam.nearClipPlane).magnitude;
        float screenThickness = dstToNearClipPlaneCorner;

        Transform screenT = screen.transform;
        bool camFacingSameDirAsPortal = Vector3.Dot (transform.forward, transform.position - viewPoint) > 0;
        screenT.localScale = new Vector3 (screenT.localScale.x, screenT.localScale.y, screenThickness);
        screenT.localPosition = Vector3.forward * screenThickness * ((camFacingSameDirAsPortal) ? 0.5f : -0.5f);
        return screenThickness;
    }

    void UpdateSliceParams (PortalTraveller traveller) {
        // Calculate slice normal
        int side = SideOfPortal (traveller.transform.position);
        Vector3 sliceNormal = transform.forward * -side;
        Vector3 cloneSliceNormal = linkedPortal.transform.forward * side;

        // Calculate slice centre
        Vector3 slicePos = transform.position;
        Vector3 cloneSlicePos = linkedPortal.transform.position;

        // Adjust slice offset so that when player standing on other side of portal to the object, the slice doesn't clip through
        float sliceOffsetDst = 0;
        float cloneSliceOffsetDst = 0;
        float screenThickness = screen.transform.localScale.z;

        bool playerSameSideAsTraveller = SameSideOfPortal (playerCam.transform.position, traveller.transform.position);
        if (!playerSameSideAsTraveller) {
            sliceOffsetDst = -screenThickness;
        }
        bool playerSameSideAsCloneAppearing = side != linkedPortal.SideOfPortal (playerCam.transform.position);
        if (!playerSameSideAsCloneAppearing) {
            cloneSliceOffsetDst = -screenThickness;
        }

        // Apply parameters
        for (int i = 0; i < traveller.originalMaterials.Length; i++) {
            traveller.originalMaterials[i].SetVector ("sliceCentre", slicePos);
            traveller.originalMaterials[i].SetVector ("sliceNormal", sliceNormal);
            traveller.originalMaterials[i].SetFloat ("sliceOffsetDst", sliceOffsetDst);

            traveller.cloneMaterials[i].SetVector ("sliceCentre", cloneSlicePos);
            traveller.cloneMaterials[i].SetVector ("sliceNormal", cloneSliceNormal);
            traveller.cloneMaterials[i].SetFloat ("sliceOffsetDst", cloneSliceOffsetDst);

        }

    }

    // Use custom projection matrix to align portal camera's near clip plane with the surface of the portal
    // Note that this affects precision of the depth buffer, which can cause issues with effects like screenspace AO
    void SetNearClipPlane () {
        // Learning resource:
        // http://www.terathon.com/lengyel/Lengyel-Oblique.pdf
        Transform clipPlane = transform;
        int dot = System.Math.Sign (Vector3.Dot (clipPlane.forward, transform.position - portalCam.transform.position));

        Vector3 camSpacePos = portalCam.worldToCameraMatrix.MultiplyPoint (clipPlane.position);
        Vector3 camSpaceNormal = portalCam.worldToCameraMatrix.MultiplyVector (clipPlane.forward) * dot;
        float camSpaceDst = -Vector3.Dot (camSpacePos, camSpaceNormal) + nearClipOffset;

        // Don't use oblique clip plane if very close to portal as it seems this can cause some visual artifacts
        if (Mathf.Abs (camSpaceDst) > nearClipLimit) {
            Vector4 clipPlaneCameraSpace = new Vector4 (camSpaceNormal.x, camSpaceNormal.y, camSpaceNormal.z, camSpaceDst);

            // Update projection based on new clip plane
            // Calculate matrix with player cam so that player camera settings (fov, etc) are used
            portalCam.projectionMatrix = playerCam.CalculateObliqueMatrix (clipPlaneCameraSpace);
        } else {
            portalCam.projectionMatrix = playerCam.projectionMatrix;
        }
    }

    void OnTravellerEnterPortal (PortalTraveller traveller) {
        if (!trackedTravellers.Contains (traveller)) {
            traveller.EnterPortalThreshold ();
            traveller.previousOffsetFromPortal = traveller.transform.position - transform.position;
            trackedTravellers.Add (traveller);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other) {
        var traveller = other.GetComponent<PortalTraveller> ();
        if (traveller) {
            OnTravellerEnterPortal (traveller);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit (Collider other) {
        var traveller = other.GetComponent<PortalTraveller> ();
        if (traveller && trackedTravellers.Contains (traveller)) {
            traveller.ExitPortalThreshold ();
            trackedTravellers.Remove (traveller);
        }
    }

    /*
     ** Some helper/convenience stuff:
     */

    int SideOfPortal (Vector3 pos) {
        return System.Math.Sign (Vector3.Dot (pos - transform.position, transform.forward));
    }

    bool SameSideOfPortal (Vector3 posA, Vector3 posB) {
        return SideOfPortal (posA) == SideOfPortal (posB);
    }

    Vector3 portalCamPos {
        get {
            return portalCam.transform.position;
        }
    }

    void OnValidate () {
        if (linkedPortal != null) {
            linkedPortal.linkedPortal = this;
        }
    }
}
```

PortalTraveller.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PortalTraveller : MonoBehaviour {

    [Header("Traveller Configuration")]
    public GameObject graphicsObject;
    public GameObject graphicsClone { get; set; }
    public Vector3 previousOffsetFromPortal { get; set; }

    public Material[] originalMaterials { get; set; }
    public Material[] cloneMaterials { get; set; }

    public virtual void Teleport (Transform fromPortal, Transform toPortal, Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot) {
        transform.position = pos;
        transform.rotation = rot;
    }

    // Called when first touches portal
    public virtual void EnterPortalThreshold () {
        if (graphicsClone == null) {
            graphicsClone = Instantiate (graphicsObject);
            graphicsClone.transform.parent = graphicsObject.transform.parent;
            graphicsClone.transform.localScale = graphicsObject.transform.localScale;
            originalMaterials = GetMaterials (graphicsObject);
            cloneMaterials = GetMaterials (graphicsClone);
        } else {
            graphicsClone.SetActive (true);
        }
    }

    // Called once no longer touching portal (excluding when teleporting)
    public virtual void ExitPortalThreshold () {
        graphicsClone.SetActive (false);
        // Disable slicing
        for (int i = 0; i < originalMaterials.Length; i++) {
            originalMaterials[i].SetVector ("sliceNormal", Vector3.zero);
        }
    }

    public void SetSliceOffsetDst (float dst, bool clone) {
        for (int i = 0; i < originalMaterials.Length; i++) {
            if (clone) {
                cloneMaterials[i].SetFloat ("sliceOffsetDst", dst);
            } else {
                originalMaterials[i].SetFloat ("sliceOffsetDst", dst);
            }

        }
    }

    Material[] GetMaterials (GameObject g) {
        var renderers = g.GetComponentsInChildren<MeshRenderer> ();
        var matList = new List<Material> ();
        foreach (var renderer in renderers) {
            foreach (var mat in renderer.sharedMaterials)
            {
                matList.Add (mat);
            }
        }
        return matList.ToArray ();
    }
}
```

MainCamera.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MainCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    Portal[] portals;

    void Awake () {
        portals = FindObjectsOfType<Portal> ();
    }

    void LateUpdate() {

        for (int i = 0; i < portals.Length; i++) {
            portals[i].PrePortalRender ();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < portals.Length; i++) {
            portals[i].Render ();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < portals.Length; i++) {
            portals[i].PostPortalRender ();
        }

    }

}
```

CameraUtility.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class CameraUtility {
    static readonly Vector3[] cubeCornerOffsets = {
        new Vector3 (1, 1, 1),
        new Vector3 (-1, 1, 1),
        new Vector3 (-1, -1, 1),
        new Vector3 (-1, -1, -1),
        new Vector3 (-1, 1, -1),
        new Vector3 (1, -1, -1),
        new Vector3 (1, 1, -1),
        new Vector3 (1, -1, 1),
    };

    // http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/IsVisibleFrom
    public static bool VisibleFromCamera (Renderer renderer, Camera camera) {
        Plane[] frustumPlanes = GeometryUtility.CalculateFrustumPlanes (camera);
        return GeometryUtility.TestPlanesAABB (frustumPlanes, renderer.bounds);
    }

    public static bool BoundsOverlap (MeshFilter nearObject, MeshFilter farObject, Camera camera) {

        var near = GetScreenRectFromBounds (nearObject, camera);
        var far = GetScreenRectFromBounds (farObject, camera);

        // ensure far object is indeed further away than near object
        if (far.zMax > near.zMin) {
            // Doesn't overlap on x axis
            if (far.xMax < near.xMin || far.xMin > near.xMax) {
                return false;
            }
            // Doesn't overlap on y axis
            if (far.yMax < near.yMin || far.yMin > near.yMax) {
                return false;
            }
            // Overlaps
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // With thanks to http://www.turiyaware.com/a-solution-to-unitys-camera-worldtoscreenpoint-causing-ui-elements-to-display-when-object-is-behind-the-camera/
    public static MinMax3D GetScreenRectFromBounds (MeshFilter renderer, Camera mainCamera) {
        MinMax3D minMax = new MinMax3D (float.MaxValue, float.MinValue);

        Vector3[] screenBoundsExtents = new Vector3[8];
        var localBounds = renderer.sharedMesh.bounds;
        bool anyPointIsInFrontOfCamera = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            Vector3 localSpaceCorner = localBounds.center + Vector3.Scale (localBounds.extents, cubeCornerOffsets[i]);
            Vector3 worldSpaceCorner = renderer.transform.TransformPoint (localSpaceCorner);
            Vector3 viewportSpaceCorner = mainCamera.WorldToViewportPoint (worldSpaceCorner);

            if (viewportSpaceCorner.z > 0) {
                anyPointIsInFrontOfCamera = true;
            } else {
                // If point is behind camera, it gets flipped to the opposite side
                // So clamp to opposite edge to correct for this
                viewportSpaceCorner.x = (viewportSpaceCorner.x <= 0.5f) ? 1 : 0;
                viewportSpaceCorner.y = (viewportSpaceCorner.y <= 0.5f) ? 1 : 0;
            }

            // Update bounds with new corner point
            minMax.AddPoint (viewportSpaceCorner);
        }

        // All points are behind camera so just return empty bounds
        if (!anyPointIsInFrontOfCamera) {
            return new MinMax3D ();
        }

        return minMax;
    }

    public struct MinMax3D {
        public float xMin;
        public float xMax;
        public float yMin;
        public float yMax;
        public float zMin;
        public float zMax;

        public MinMax3D (float min, float max) {
            this.xMin = min;
            this.xMax = max;
            this.yMin = min;
            this.yMax = max;
            this.zMin = min;
            this.zMax = max;
        }

        public void AddPoint (Vector3 point) {
            xMin = Mathf.Min (xMin, point.x);
            xMax = Mathf.Max (xMax, point.x);
            yMin = Mathf.Min (yMin, point.y);
            yMax = Mathf.Max (yMax, point.y);
            zMin = Mathf.Min (zMin, point.z);
            zMax = Mathf.Max (zMax, point.z);
        }
    }

}
```

FlashlightOffset.cs (Basically I wanted a little delay between the movement of the camera and the flashlight, when I added the flashlight to the portal rendering camera I also added this script with it):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlashlightOffset : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 vectOffSet;
    private GameObject goFollow;
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 3f;
    [SerializeField] private bool portalFlashlight = false;

    void Start()
    {
        if (!portalFlashlight) goFollow = Camera.main.gameObject;
        else goFollow = transform.parent.GetChild(2).gameObject;
        vectOffSet = transform.position - goFollow.transform.position;
    }


    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = goFollow.transform.position;// + vectOffSet;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, goFollow.transform.rotation, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

That's it, got no clue about why the rendering camera flashlight will stop moving when you look to the corners of the portal.

OBS: Also, I upgrade my project to URP, everything works as intended.

Comment: First idea is the way to go (the second would require some hardcore cusom code) but you need to post your existing code so we can help diagnose what's going wrong. As a start you'd need to calculate the size and angle of the light passing through based on the distance to the portal, any occulders and the angle setting of the spotlight itself.

Comment: Sure thing Absinthe, edited the post and added the code. Sorry for taking quite long to reply, I was really busy with this crazy exam week. If you need any more information please let me know and I will add it here :)